# How do you select a string value left of a specified section of a string, not including empty space?

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla javascript, how do you select the first string value left of a specified section of a string and not include the empty space?

For example, there is a string `1 hr 30 min`

How do you get the `1` value left of `hr` and how do you get the `30` value left of `min`?

```
var string = "1 hr 30 min";
if (string.includes("hr")) {
    // get the 1 value
}
if (string.includes("min")) {
    // get the 30 value
}
```

Comment: use regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function will split your string into two string, containing only hours and win, then you just have to parse it ton integer :

```
const getHoursAndMin = () => {
  const _string = string.replace('min','')
  const [hours,min] = _string.split('hr')
  console.log(parseInt(hours),parseInt(min))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way, you will have good control on the way out.

If you can guarantee the input string in the function.

```js
"use strict";
function zeroFill(str, width) {
    width -= str.toString().length;
    if (width > 0) {
        return new Array(width + (/\./.test(str) ? 2 : 1)).join('0') + str;
    }
    return str + ""; // always return a string
}
function getHoursOrMin(str, extract, returnType) {
    const _str = str.split(' ');
    let result = "";
    switch (extract) {
        case 'hr':
            const iHr = _str.indexOf('hr');
            result = _str[iHr - 1];
            break;
        case 'min':
            const iMin = _str.indexOf('min');
            result = _str[iMin - 1];
            break;
    }
    switch (returnType) {
        case 'number':
            return Number(result);
        case 'string':
            return result;
        case 'stringZeroFill':
            return zeroFill(result, 2);
    }
}
const str = "1 hr 30 min";
console.log(`${getHoursOrMin(str, 'hr', 'number')}:${getHoursOrMin(str, 'min', 'number')}`);
console.log(`${getHoursOrMin(str, 'hr', 'string')}:${getHoursOrMin(str, 'min', 'string')}`);
console.log(`${getHoursOrMin(str, 'hr', 'stringZeroFill')}:${getHoursOrMin(str, 'min', 'stringZeroFill')}`);
```